# jQuery toggle cookie needs to have persistence in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, persistence, toggle

I have updated to the latest cookie.js and try as I may, I can't get the cookie to persist with any Internet Explorer browser. I have tried the multiple examples on stack and the web without success. I have moved the javascript under the html as suggested and I have run laps around the office in frustration.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".toggle_container").show();

$("h2.trigger").toggle(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active"); 
    }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("active");
});

$("h2.trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".toggle_container").slideToggle("slow,");
});

});
</script>
```

And the html:

```
<h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Production</a></h2>
<div class="toggle_container" id="pd">
    <div class="block">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Staff</td>
                <td>PD</td>
                <td><a href="https://snip/">https://snip/</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<h2 class="trigger"><a href="#">Development</a></h2>
<div class="toggle_container" id="dv">
    <div class="block">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>Solutions</td>
                <td>DV</td>
                <td>
                <a href="https://snip">
                https://snip</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Thanks!